# What `libcurl` options are applied when `curl_easy_send` and `curl_easy_recv` called?

Tags: c++, c, libcurl

`curl_easy_recv` and `curl_easy_send` are useful for custom protocols, so we can rely on well developed `curl` code for socket, SSL and proxy connection implementation. However, I can not find in documentation what `libcurl` options are applied when these methods are called.

For example, it is important will apply `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT` and other connection speed related properties? And what about `CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT`?

Are there any documentation that has exact list of options supported by receive and send `curl` functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

curl_easy_recv and curl_easy_send are really the bastard children of libcurl. They're totally you asked for it, you got it and basically no options affect them.

No timeout options have any effect, no speed limits or speed caps and no protocol-specific magic. These functions are simply very thin layered on top of the network send/receive functions and that is all they do.

We usually, rather strongly, urge users to avoid using these functions if at all possible. If you do a transfer using a protocol libcurl supports, using these functions is very rarely the right answer.